# what does "To err is human; to err humble is divine" mean?

Tags: meaning

Read this in an article referring to "the best way to introduce yourself" and wanted more clarity on this statement "To err is human; to err humble is divine"

Comment: Is this transcribed correctly?  Standard conventions would dictate an adverb in the second clause: "to err *humbly* is divine".

Comment: And the original quote is [To err is human, to forgive divine](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/to-err-is-human-to-forgive-divine)

Answer (score 1):

[To err](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/err) means to make a mistake.

> To err is human.

Is a standard expression to say that everybody can make mistakes (and *does* make them), it is a human trait.

It is often followed by another sentence to contrast it with.

In this case, the meaning is that everybody can make mistakes, but if you make a mistake and you are humble about it, you are better than just human, you are divine (godlike). It may be a bit of a literary exaggeration, of course.

A well-known variation is:

> To err is human. To really screw things up, you need a computer.

Comment: how can one no be humble about erring?

Comment: If you really don't know that, that is great! For a lot of people it is very easy not to be humble about it: make an error and pretend it is correct, make an error and blame another, make an error and deny it, there are thousands of ways people can err and be ignorant, arrogant or in other ways anything _but_ humble about it :)

Comment: oh, i get what you mean. i was assuming that one *knew* that one has erred and still didn't remain humble.

Comment: Sometimes people _know_ but they can still be arrogant about it. "yes my answer was wrong. But that was because John gave me the wrong information!" or worse: "So? What if my answer was wrong? Maybe you should have asked another question!"